# update xml attribute in xml returns error SQL

Tags: sql, xml

Im trying to update an attribute of an xml in SQL.

My XML is stored on a variable **@tmpRespXML**:

```
<Responses>
  <x id="3" name="Good" val="0" seq="0" createsr="0" />
  <x id="4" name="Fair" val="0" seq="0" createsr="0" />
  <x id="5" name="Needs Repair" val="1" seq="0" createsr="0" />
  <x id="6" name="Not Inspected" val="1" seq="0" createsr="0" />
  <x id="7" name="N/A" val="1" seq="0" createsr="0" />
</Responses>
```

So what I did is to put the xml in a temp table.

```
DECLARE @tmpRespTBL TABLE(Responses XML)
INSERT @tmpRespTBL VALUES(@tmpRespXML)
```

and then update the table. I'm trying to set the attribute **@createsr** to 1 where my attribute **@id** is **equal** to **@items**

```
UPDATE @tmpRespTBL
SET Responses.modify('replace value of(/Responses/x[@id=("'+@items+'")]/@createsr)[1] with "1"')
```

This returns the ff error:

> Msg 8172, Level 16, State 1, Line 30 The argument 1 of the xml data
>   type method "modify" must be a string literal.

What am I missing here?

Comment: not sure if this will work but, try to replace `"1"` with `1`.

Comment: try 
`SET Responses.modify('replace value of(/Responses/x[@id=(''' + @items + ''')]/@createsr)[1] with "1"')`

Comment: returns the same error.. is there something wrong with my xml?

Comment: for the last time try this `SET Responses.modify('replace value of(/Responses/x[@id=[sql:variable("@items")]]/@createsr)[1] with "1"')`

Comment: @items is a variable i declared somewhere in the code so i changed it to "'+@items+'" and still got the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
SET Responses.modify('replace value of(/Responses/x[@id=("''+@items+''")]/@createsr)[1] with "1"')
```

That should fix your issue. What I did here is escape the `'`